# Swift: Get UITableView frame when initializing custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom TableViewCell with a subview called blueView. I would like to set the width of blueView to the width of TableView. How can I determine the frame for TableView?

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

    let blueView = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        blueView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [width of tableView], 10)
        blueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        contentView.addSubview(blueView)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. At this point the cell simply does not have a frame.

You have two options.

1. Switch to Auto-Layout
2. Overwrite `layoutSubviews()`

   e.g.

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()

       let width = CGRectGetWidth(frame)

       let someFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 10)
       someView.frame = someFrame
   }
   ```