# Assigning property of custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

- I am using the below custom `UITableViewCell` without nib file.
- I have no problem in viewing it in my `UITableViewController`.
- My problem is with assigning a text to `"name"` label  `cell.name.text = "a Name"` .. noting is assigned

Can you help me?

```
import UIKit

class ACMenuCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var name : UILabel!
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        name = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 10, self.bounds.size.width , 25))
        name.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
        self.contentView.addSubview(name)
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: May you please add code of following `method`.?

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!`

Comment: `self.bounds.size.width` is most likely 0 in init.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Swift: Get UITableView frame when initializing custom UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143984/swift-get-uitableview-frame-when-initializing-custom-uitableviewcell/28144062#28144062)

Comment: If you are using the below custom UITableViewCell without nib file how have you created the IBOutlet for the name UILabel. Are you using storyboard prototype cell?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma here is the method:

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let reuseIdentifierAC:NSString = "ACMenuCell";

        
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifierAC, forIndexPath:indexPath) as ACMenuCell

            cell = ACMenuCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierAC)
            cell.name.text = "a Name"
            cell.name.textColor = .blackColor()

            return cell
        
      
    }

Comment: @user3435374 .. no . but I just use it in my tests to show text in label

Comment: @AbhishekSharma also I added this code in viewdidload         tableView.registerClass(ACMenuCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ACMenuCell")

Comment: replace `name = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 10, self.bounds.size.width , 25))` with `name = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 10, 100 , 25))` and see what happens.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Nothing changed except the label width . Here is a snapshot http://s8.postimg.org/4hk9nrsw5/image.jpg

Comment: I found the problem. it was in this line  cell = ACMenuCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierAC). After I deleted it every thing is working fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh. Why your obsession with adding bullet points to everything? It does little to improve the readability of a question.

Comment: @TRiG i am adding bullet because when any one analyze that question time its clear about this questions so that, if i am create problem then tell me i'm next time remember your complement

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this: Create a public function in a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and inside this funxtion set the text to label.

```
(void)initializeCell
{
do whatever like setting the text for label which is a subview of tableViewCell
}
```

And from `cellForRowAtIndexPAth`, call this function on cell object:

```
// taking your code for demo

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { let reuseIdentifierAC:NSString = "ACMenuCell"; var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifierAC, forIndexPath:indexPath) as ACMenuCell cell = ACMenuCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierAC) [cell initializeCell] return cell }
```

This approach has worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, I just resolve the problem by deleting cell = ACMenuCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierAC) from cellForRowAtIndexPath method